# Rails test fail with undefined method `password_digest=' after rollback from devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails app, with a User model and controller, and user tests that were green until I created a git branch wherein I was setting up devise for user authentication.  I passed that branch off to someone else to work on, and locally I rolled back the db and switched back to another branch. Now my tests are no longer green.

The error is

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `password_digest=' for #<User:0x00007fe29d2fec48>
    Did you mean?  password=
        test/models/user_test.rb:6:in `setup'
```

The user model has `has_secure_password`, the database also has the `password_digest` column in the Users table.

Has anyone else run into this problem after rolling back from devise?  It's just a local environment issue.  I can push the code to the pipeline and the tests run fine there, where there was no devise setup performed.

Things I've tried:

- dropping the databases (Dev and test) and running migration from start
- double check the Gemfile and run bundle install
- remove the has_secure_password from the User model

Answer (score 1):

Posting this in case it helps someone else:

This worked

I deleted the Gemfile.lock and ran `bundle install`.

‍♀️ I should have known